# Description of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I'm again stuck in an algebra exercise. 
[image]

I'm not sure if I understand the problem right. Could it be that I have to show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\gamma$ can be expressed by a product of finite abelian groups? Could somebody give me a hint, how to start with this exercise?
Thanks a lot

Comment: First, understand that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(\gamma)$ _is_ a finite abelian group.

Comment: remember that an odd prime in $Z$ is a prime in $Z[i]$ iff it has the form $4n+3$, whilst $2=(1+i)(1-i)$

Comment: @DavidHolden ok, I understand that a prime p in $\mathbb{Z}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if an d only if it has the form 4n+3, this means that p $\equiv$ 3 mod 4. On the other hand if p can be written as $p=a^2+b^2$ we get that p $\equiv$ 1 mod 4. So this implies that $(a_j)^2+(b_j)^2$ are coprime to $q_k$

Comment: http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=199730

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thanks, seems like the same course